# Removing parentheses from date only in bibliography with natbib

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I am using `natbib` with `agsm` style to achieve Harvard style referencing.

Is there any way to remove the parenthesis around the year in the references section (not the citations in the main text)? I tried `dcu` instead of `agsm` which sorts of achieves it but puts a colon instead, which I don't want either. Is there any bst that matches the style I am looking for (which seems to be the style lots of Universities require too). It is well described here too: http://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm

So in a nutshell I wish to achieve this:

**Boughton, J.M., 2002. The Bretton Woods proposal: an indepth look. Political Science Quarterly, 42(6), pp.564-78**.

Instead of this:

**Boughton, J.M. (2002), The Bretton Woods proposal: an indepth look. Political Science Quarterly, 42(6), pp.564-78.**

Thanks.

Comment: Uh... Why not use [this](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/)?

Comment: @Seamus: because it does exactly the same as natbib, as you can see in the documentation which uses precisely the agsm style.

Comment: I edited the title to make it reflect the question actually being asked. Hope that's ok.

Comment: @Seamus: 'harvard' is an old package which was superseded by natbib (I tried it but for some reason it generated the bibliography with the author's first name initials first instead of after the surname, and for some reason did not compress multiple citations by the same author when put in one cite).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following after having loaded **natbib**

```
\renewcommand\harvardyearleft{\unskip, }
\renewcommand\harvardyearright[1]{.}
```

The first usually inserts a `(`, while the second inserts a `)`. We redefine the former to backspace and insert a comma and a space, the latter to gobble the comma and insert the period.