# Styling references using natbib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

This should be a really simple question, but I really wasn't able to find it in this forum.

The editor of a publication that I'm writing for (Cambridge Journals) asks me to use harvard-style references.

Looking at `.bst` files and other fonts I was able to find that the best approximations to the desired style are `authordate1` and `dcu`.

---

This is what I get using `authordate1` (problem: authors last names are not abbreviated):

> Dennis, Carina. 2002. Biology databases: Information overload. Nature,
>   417(6884), 14-14.
>
> Maccagnan, Alessandro, Riva, Mauro, Feltrin, Erika, Simionati,
>   Barbara, Vardanega, Tullio, Valle, Giorgio, & Cannata, Nicola. 2010.
>   Combining ontologies and workflows to design formal protocols for
>   biological laboratories. Automated Experimentation, 2(1), 1-14.

---

This is what I get using `dcu` (problems: year is surrounded by parentheses and does not use '&' for the last author):

> Dennis, C. (2002). Biology databases: Information overload, Nature
>   417(6884): 14-14.
>
> Maccagnan, A., Riva, M., Feltrin, E., Simionati, B., Vardanega, T.,
>   Valle, G. and Cannata, N. (2010).Combining ontologies and workows to
>   design formal protocols for biological laboratories, Automated
>   Experimentation 2(1): 1-14.

---

And this is what I want:

> Dennis, C. 2002. Biology databases: Information overload, Nature
>   417(6884): 14-14.
>
> Maccagnan, A., Riva, M., Feltrin, E., Simionati, B., Vardanega, T.,
>   Valle, G. & Cannata, N. 2010.Combining ontologies and workows to
>   design formal protocols for biological laboratories, Automated
>   Experimentation 2(1): 1-14.

---

**Edited: Is there an easy way to edit the existing styles?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Harvard style family by using the `natbib` package to get the results asked by Cambridge Journals.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Hello.  Cite someone.

\bibliographystyle{agsm,dcu,kluwer} %choose one you like
\bibliography{yourbibfile}  

\end{document}
```

For more information, please visit the [`natbib` package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib)

Also, according to the [harvard documentation on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/harvard), there are six possible bibliography styles you can use.  Taken from the pdf:

> There are six bibliography styles currently available within the
>   harvard family, **agsm** (used in this document) which is based on Pitson
>   (1978, pp. 95–98), **dcu** which is based upon the conventions in use in
>   the Design Computing Unit, Department of Architectural and Design
>   Science, University of Sydney, **jmr** for the Journal of Management
>   Research, **jphysicsB** for the Journal of Physics B, **kluwer** which aspires
>   to conform to the requirements of Kluwer Academic Publishers and
>   **nederlands** which conforms to Dutch conventions. They are invoked by
>   the \bibliographystyle as described in Lamport (1986, p. 74) and
>   effect the layout of the entries in the bibliography. Provided there
>   is no name clash with other harvard options the bibliography style may
>   be selected by passing it as an option to the \usepackage command that
>   invokes the harvard package.

If any of these suggestions work, then ---according to [Removing parentheses from date only in bibliography with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20203/removing-parentheses-from-date-only-in-bibliography-with-natbib) ---, you can set:

> > Put the following after having loaded `natbib`
>
> ```
> \renewcommand\harvardyearleft{\unskip, }
> \renewcommand\harvardyearright[1]{.}
> ```
>
> > The first usually inserts a (, while the second inserts a ). We
> >     redefine the former to backspace and insert a comma and a space, the
> >     latter to gobble the comma and insert the period.

Regarding the last `&`, you can set this with

```
\renewcommand\harvardand[1]{\&}
```

at your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for the attention Mario. As you may have noticed, I've tried to use `dcu` style, but although it is very close to the style used by the journal I've noticed some differences which I have stated on my post (year is surrounded by parentheses and does not use '&' for the last author). `agsm` and `kluwer` are very close too, but with other differences like the use of quotes on the article titles. I've also tried to look for this in the `natbib` package documentation, but I was not able to figure this out (maybe that's because I'm a beginner :-).

Comment: @pasemes Updated answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Mario, thanks again. But, unfortunately, none of these styles exactly matches the desired result. I'm thinking the only way to resolve this is to manually modify one of the similar styles (`authordate1` and `dcu`). Howerver, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @pasemes I found how to change the parenthesis (see updated answer).  See if also adding `\renewcommad\harvardand[1]{&}` does something good.  Also try `\$` just in case (I'm not sure if it will work at all)

Comment: Bingo! That worked. Also, the harvardand was helpful (except that I had to use '\&' to escape &). Nevertheless, thanks for the persistence!